# SQL injection on django app

Tags: mysql, sql, django, sql-injection

I am writing a django app and I know it handles string escaping and all to prevent sql injections in the queryset ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/ ).

Out of curiosity, I was wondering if there are still ways to perform sql injections on django apps? What would be an example?

Comment: i.e. there could be an unknown security hole in the Django source code which allows injection of arbitrary sql commands. At least its open source and you can always look for such holes. I cant give you a real example because I dont know such hole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Take a look at the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection); it may be useful.

> By using Django's querysets, the resulting SQL will be properly
>   escaped by the underlying database driver. However, Django also gives
>   developers power to write raw queries or execute custom sql. These
>   capabilities should be used sparingly and you should always be careful
>   to properly escape any parameters that the user can control. In
>   addition, you should exercise caution when using extra().

Comment: So essentially, the only holes will be those you introduce yourself, barring some massive oversight on the Django team that opens some sort of hole, but such things are rare and are caught quickly.

Comment: Specifically: you could look through your source code for ``.raw(``: that would be code worth focussing on.